# Last item Edittext inside a RecyclerView loses focus when clicked and focuses instead on the first Edittext

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a horizontal RecyclerView containing EditTexts. Whenever I scroll to the last item on the list and click the edittext field there, the list scrolls back to the top of the list and the edittext of the first item gets focus instead.

If it helps, the horizontal RecyclerView's parent happens to be a LinearLayout populated on runtime with multiple instances of the same horizontal recyclerviews.

I tried applying various implementations of focusable, focusableInTouchMode, and descendantFocusability in xml of the 1) edittext itself, 2) the recyclerView, and 3) the LinearLayout.

Here is the xml for the outermost layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray7">

    <!-- Some omitted layouts -->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catalog_shop_search_layout">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/catalog_shop_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <!-- Other omitted views -->

            <!-- Dynamic ViewGroup populated dynamically -->
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/catalog_featured_category_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the xml for the dynamically populated horizontal lists:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_gray7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_small" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/catalog_category_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_normal">

        <!-- Some omitted views -->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/catalog_category_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catalog_category_name" />    

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_small_v2" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Here is the xml for the adapter going into the recyclerview

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:id="@+id/catalog_product_layout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cart_catalog_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onItemClicked(product)}"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_normal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cart_catalog_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_catalog_image_size"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:glide="@{product.image}"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder_item" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_price_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_very_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_very_small">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10dp"
            android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="₱ 33.00"
            android:textColor="@color/red2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_old_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10dp"
            android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="₱ 88.00"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="4"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2"/>

    <!-- Add to cart-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_add_to_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onAddToCartClicked(product)}"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:text="ADD TO CART"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_blue3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_item_added_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_item_added_icon"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_rounded" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_item_added_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ITEM ADDED"
            android:textColor="@color/green3"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <!-- With Quantity UI -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/catalog_product_quantity_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_quantity_minus"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:insetTop="0dip"
            android:insetBottom="0dip"
            android:minWidth="0dip"
            android:minHeight="0dip"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onSubQuantityClicked(product)}"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:cornerRadius="0dip"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_item_sub_cart"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_quantity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_item_quantity_outline"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="000"
            android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small_v2" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/catalog_product_quantity_add"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:insetTop="0dip"
            android:insetBottom="0dip"
            android:minWidth="0dip"
            android:minHeight="0dip"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onAddQuantityClicked(product)}"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:cornerRadius="0dip"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_item_add_cart"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            app:iconTint="#016d3c" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: Please provide your code so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps edited to provide xmls